# Gwt-query: get an Image from ImageData

Tags: java, gwt, canvas, gquery

I'm trying to accomplish this but I've got no clue about getting a GWT Image from a Canvas ImageData. I'm issuing this piece of code:

```
ImageData canvasImageData = canvas.getContext2d().getImageData(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

My purpose is to get the Image somehow, any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an `Image` from your canvas you should use [Canvas.toDataUrl()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html#toDataUrl%28%29), which will give you the image data encoded as a string which can be used as the `src` attribute for an `<img>` tag.

```
Image canvasImage = new Image(canvas.toDataUrl());
```